# httponly cookie is not letting me login to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cookies

To make my site secure. I added this to my apache configuration includes.

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

And now I get this error when trying to login to wordpress:

*ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.*

Is the code wrong or do I need to do change some setting on my Wordpress too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your PHP .ini to, try this in your wp-config.php file above the "Thats all" comment

```
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly','On');
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure','On');
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies','On');
```

Comment: Added this code to config and php.ini file . Still doesn't work!